# Finding a function $f$ such that $h \circ g = g \circ f$ for $h$ bijective, $g$ injective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B$ be sets. Let $h: B \to B$ be bijective and $g: A \to B$ be injective. Does there exist an $f:A \to A$ such that $h \circ g = g \circ f$? If this is not true in general, what different conditions do we need?

If $g$ were surjective, then we know it has a right inverse $k$, and so we can simply let $f = k \circ h \circ g$. This kind of trick doesn't seem to work when $g$ is injective. This makes me think that it just doesn't work in this case, but I can't find a counterexample.

Comment: Let $A$ have one point, $h(g(a)) \neq g(a) $. The answer is no.

Comment: Ah yeah, that works. Then what extra conditions do we need to make it work, without making $g$ bijective?

Comment: If $g$ is not surjective, there's always the risk that $h$ takes some point of the image of $g$ to $B\setminus g(A)$, in which case you couldn't have $h\circ g=g\circ f$ for any $f$.